# Attach middleware to all method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this in Laravel 4.2 `Route::when('*', 'csrf', ['post']);` that insert csrf verification to all post, how can I port to Larevel 5.2 ?

This is my own csrf, without using default provide by Laravel:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Input;
class VerifyCsrfToken1
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = $request->ajax() ? $request->header('X-CSRF-Token') : $request->input('_token');
        if ($request->session()->token() === $token) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        throw new TokenMismatchException;
    }
}
```

I created my personal csrf middleware, but I don't know how to attach them on ALL post request

I want to attach it to all post via `Route`'s facade. (file routes.php)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5 wires up middleware a bit differently, you won't be doing this through the `Request` facade.

You want to first register your Middleware as global. Open up `app/Http/Kernel.php` and add it to the global `$middleware` array.

```
protected $middleware = [
    VerifyCsrfToken1::class
    ...
```

Then in your middleware class, check to see if it is handling a POST request. If not, have it just pass the request along without doing anything.

```
if($request->method() != "POST") {
    // Move right along
    return $next($request);
}
```

Side note: As you noted Laravel has a `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware baked in already. I'd advise trying to adapt this if possible.

Comment: Yes sure, but I need to attach on all POST route "automatically" without make everytimes ->middleware...->middleware etc

Comment: @Davide I think you misunderstand middleware, this is how it is supposed to work. You setup a series of middleware classes that get to examine each request and make decisions.

Comment: @Davide You're thinking like Laravel 4, but Laravel 5 has reworked this significantly. Make your own middleware classes follow the pattern of the existing baked-in middleware classes!

Comment: Uhm @jszobody , I create a routeMiddleware, so in this case I can create a middleware :D ?

Comment: @Davide sure you can create routeMiddleware for individual routes or groups. but middleware that _automatically_ handles _all_ POST requests should be global.

Comment: @Davide you're welcome! I find that my life is significantly easier if I can adjust my thinking to the way Laravel is designed, rather than trying to force Laravel to behave the way I want. Good luck.